# How to improve this with a 2 dimensional array

Tags: java

Hi I have created a 2 dimensional array that allows the user to enter a word and it then tells them the Price. How would i be able to improve this Program by using a for loop? Thanks for future reply's and sorry for bad editing!

```
String[][] the ={
     {"Best Health Basic","R450.00"},
     {"Best Health Basic Plus","R575.00"},
     {"Best Health Premium","700.00"},
     {"Best Health Premium Plus","950.00"}};

String INPUT = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter one of the following\nBest Health Basic\nBest Health Basic Plus\nBest Health Premium\nBest Health Premium Plus");

if (the[0][0].equalsIgnoreCase(INPUT))  {
    System.out.println("found it " + the[0][1]);
    return;
}  

if (the[1][0].equalsIgnoreCase(INPUT)) {
    System.out.println("found it " + the[1][1]);
    return;
} 

if (the[2][0].equalsIgnoreCase(INPUT)) {
    System.out.println("found it " + the[2][1]);
    return;
} 

if (the[3][0].equalsIgnoreCase(INPUT)) {
    System.out.println("found it " + the[3][1]);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `for-loop` to loop from 0 to the length of your array. Good practise is to use the length of variable (`the.length = 4`).

```
for (int i=0; i<the.length; i++) {
    if (the[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(INPUT)) {
        System.out.println("found it " + the[i][1]);
        return;
    }
}
```

---

However a better practise would be using `HashMap`, that stores a pair `value-key`:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Best Health Basic","R450.00");
map.put("Best Health Basic Plus","R575.00");
map.put("Best Health Premium","700.00");
map.put("Best Health Premium Plus","950.00");

System.out.println("found it " + map.get(INPUT));
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `return` to break the loop. A `break` makes more sense.

Comment: @MatthewDiana: It depends. We currently don't know his intention more.

Comment: It doesn't depend. Using a `return` would break him out of his `main` method and make him more confused.

Comment: How do you know this is in the `main` method?

Comment: I'd also not use an array but a map to do this kind of query.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thanks for suggestions as well.

Comment: It is used in my main method @NikolasCharalambidis

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < theArrayWithPrices.length; i++) {
  if (theArrayWithPrices[i][0].toLowerCase().contains(userInput.toLowerCase())) {
     System.out.println("Product " + theArrayWithPrices[i][0] + " costs " + theArrayWithPrices[i][1]);
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. calling an array "the" isnt helpful
2. calling a variable INPUT is violating java naming conventions; thus I gave both variables a more telling name
3. I am using [String.contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))() - or do you really want that people have to **exactly** write down the name of the product; with its full length and glory?

And honestly, this is super-basic stuff. You seriously want to do more self-study; for example by turning to the excellent tutorials from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/); and work through the "basics".

Comment: The example that the question gives me shows that the user must enter the full word. @GhostCat

Comment: I gave you hints how to *improve* your program. Yes, I improved more than that loop. But even when you are a beginner; you should understand that these are only suggestions. To make you think about such stuff, you know.

Comment: Oh no of course, any sort of suggestion help! i was just giving you the reason as to why i wanted to get a full word instead of just a part of the word@GhostCat

Comment: Sure. Btw: if you got what you were looking for... don't forget about accepting your preferred answer.